# Sass setup for Meteor JS App

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have the Meteor app setup with such folder structure. I am not able to get the sass or scss file to create the appropriate css on its own and serve it to the client.

What should I do to make sass work as I prefer sass over scss.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor supports less and stylus out of box my issuing `meteor add less` or `meteor add stylus` in your project root directory.

there is also a third party [package repository](https://atmosphere.meteor.com) (to be rolled into meteor core in the near future) on which you can find alternatives to many requirements.

For example, there is a third party [scss package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/scss) you can add to your project with `meteorite add scss`.

Now, the `meteorite` command here belongs to an [npm package](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) that interfaces your app to the atmosphere package repository as well as provide some deeper packaging structure to your app.

When you add the scss package, like in a typical meteor application your coffeescript, handlebars,jade,less,scss,javascript etc files will be compiled/bundled at deploy time and at each save afterwards and be placed in a hidden directory. So you will not be seeing your compiled css alongside your scss files, but the css will have been sent to the browser.

Comment: Stylus seems more like Sass and will be using that in my project. Thanks!

Comment: scss package link is broken